# can i set django model paranoid which acts like in Sequelize.js

Tags: django, sequelize.js, django-orm

```
// don't delete database entries but set the newly added attribute deletedAt
// to the current date (when deletion was done). paranoid will only work if
// timestamps are enabled
paranoid: true,
```

I used Sequelize.js ORM, and there was option paranoid like above description. (from  [Sequelize.js tutorial docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html))

I want to make my Django Model paranoid.

I googled with keywords like "django paranoid", but i couldn't find informations. What is a general name for the option "paranoid" and how can i make my django model act like the option?
Or should I make mixins or middlewares to make paranoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course, you can use [django-paranoid](https://github.com/drneox/django-paranoid)

this library will add deleted_at, updated_at and created_at field, also a soft delete method.

You only need extend to model with ParanoidModel.

For see the deleted object you can use objects_with_deleted:

```
MyModel.objects_with_deleted.last()
```

and if do you want do hard delete an object you only should use True param:

```
m = MyModel.objects.last()
m.delete(True)
```